# How to load a client app.config file for a dll

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Service and Client DLL which has the proxy class for my WCF Service.  My client dll is going run by a different exe.  I have restrictions in adding my client app.config file to the exe location.  I cannot do this myExe.exe.config.  I want to load the client app.config file in the client dll itself or the app.config file should be loaded from a different location.

And my exe is C++.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

To explicitly load a particular config, you need to launch the object in a separate AppDomain. Use one of the AppDomain.CreateDomain overloads that takes an AppDomainSetup where you can pass in the path to the config file. Yout need to make sure any return values can be marshalled across AppDomain boundaries. No, there isn't an easier way to do this that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a standard issue with .NET. In general, when you create a separate project which will build into a dll, you can create settings in an app.config file. These settings are not automatically made part of the web.config of the application which uses the DLL.

The "solution" has always been: copy and paste from your library's app.config and paste into the app.config or web.config of the consuming application.

This actually makes a certain amount of sense: these configuration settings are meant to be changed based on the environment in which the code is executing. One set of configuration for your WCF client, stored in a single location, brings us back to the days of the registry.